# How to create records that validate each other with factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Here's my models :

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
  validate :parent_must_have_child_status_1
  def parent_must_have_child_status_1
    errors.add(:base, :no_child_status_1) if children.all? {|c| c.status != 1}
  end
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parent
  validates :parent, :presence => true
end
```

and my factories :

```
factory :parent do
  children { [FactoryGirl.build(:child, :status=>1)] }
end
factory :child  do
  parent
end
```

and result of FactoryGirl.create

```
FactoryGirl.create(:parent) #=> SystemStackError: stack level too deep
FactoryGirl.create(:child) #=> SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

I want to solve those errors. 
I tried several things but I couldn't solve them.
How could I create a parent and child factory in this situation?

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your factories:

I above code, i you create a parent it will create a child which again create a parent object .this will recursively happen thats y u r getting "Stack ?Level Too Deep" error.
Same for the child also.

**Maybe you should try this**

factory :parent do |p|

p.sequence(:name) {|n| "John #{n}" }

end

factory :child  do |c|

c.parents {|parents| [parents.association(:parent)] }

end

Answer (score 0):

I use to do something like this:

```
factory :parent do
  after(:create) do |parent|
    parent.children << FactoryGirl.create(:child, :status=>1)
  end
end
```

It works pretty well.